# Attempting to use QEMU/UTM on Mac - installation of Windows requires chntpw

Tags: homebrew, macports

I am attempting to follow the instructions for using UTM on Mac and then to build a Windows VM.

The first issue is that when I try to download the The script that apparently builds the ISO for windows uup_download_macos.sh, it requires some utilities. The instructions say to use Homebrew, but I am sort of committed to Macports and they do not play well together. I was able to get all the utilities from Macports except chntpw (which is listed as minacle/chntpw/chntpw).

Is there a way to get chntpw in some other way?

I was thinking to set up a macOS VM with brew, and get it there, but that is a lot of work if there is a simpler way.

EDIT 1:

I decided to go for the macOS VM. I see that @Marc Wilson has made the same suggestion.

So using Parallels, I set up a Monterey VM, installed brew, and built chntpw. Was not sure how many files were needed from that installation, but hoped that it was just the one installed as /opt/homebrew/bin/chntpw. So I copied that file into the host mac /usr/local/bin.

Turns out that was enough to run the uup_download_macos.sh script. It ran to completion and left an ISO file for Windows.

Created a new UTM virtual machine using that ISO, and proceeded to install Windows.

So far, this seems like half credit to @Mark Wilson and half credit to me, as this approach was part of my original question.

Comment: Spin up a macOS VM with UTM.  Do what you need inside of that.  Then delete the VM.  I wouldn't allow Homebrew on my machine either.

Comment: @Marc Wilson -- just curious: what are your reasons for not wanting Homebrew?

Comment: I don't agree with the project's stance on security.  https://saagarjha.com/blog/2019/04/26/thoughts-on-macos-package-managers/

Comment: Interesting read!